# How to position child element fixed to spot on page without overlapping other elements on page resize?

Tags: html, css, css-position

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcV7X.jpg)

[image: img2]

As shown in image1, I have two containers. I am trying to make it so that the "About this developer" container is fixed to where it is and even as the page scrolls it stays in that position. I tried making it position: fixed which works but then when I make the screen bigger the gap grows substantially or when I make the screen smaller it overlaps as shown in img2.

For the page layout it is one container with display flex that has two children. child1 is the image container and child 2 is the "about this developer" container. I made the parent position relative but that does nothing.

I am not sure how to accomplish this task, for a better example of what I'm trying to accomplish you can checkout instagrams online website, I am trying to recreate how they scroll and have the side container fixed.

```
<div class='main-cont'>
    <div class='child1'></div>
    <div class='child2'></div>
</div>


.main-cont{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}
.child2{
    display: fixed;
    width: 33%;
    right: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below code:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin: auto;
}
.main-cont {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.child1 {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.child2 {
  width: 33%;
}
.child2 ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.child2 ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='main-cont'>
    <div class='child1'>
      <img width="100%" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453728013993-6d66e9c9123a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80">
    </div>
    <div class='child2'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```